# Symfony > 3.2 - env() - ¿Cómo asignar DBNAME en inicio de sesión?

Tags: variables, symfony3, doctrine2

Estoy tratando de utilizar las variables de entorno en Symfony pero no logro asignar el nombre de la base de datos.

El ejemplo sería una vez inicia sesión el usuario consulta a una base de datos de acceso el nombre de la base de datos donde debe conectarse(DB_NAME). Para no tener 100 entity manager y el resto de credenciales son las mismas poder asignar a env(DB_NAME) el nombre de la bdd.

En config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: acceso
        connections:
            acceso:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            dinamica:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   "%env(DB_NAME)%"
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: acceso
database_user: usuario
database_password: contrasena
env(DB_NAME): acceso ## valor por defecto
```

LoginController.php

¿Cómo hacer set de la variable de entorno `env(DB_NAME)` en este controlador?

Comment: Gracias por la modificación @lois6b ;)

Comment: Nada , tricotrin. Para hacerlo puedes seleccionar el codigo y pulsar `ctrl + k` o el boton con forma  `{}`. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias formas de hacerlo...

La primera, usando `putenv`:

```
<?php
putenv('DB_NAME=nombredelabasededatos'); // Clave=Valor.
```

La segunda, usando `$_ENV`

```
<?php
$_ENV['DB_NAME'] = 'nombredelabasededatos';
```